# Remove all labels from Esri basemap for use in server run application

Tags: arcgis-server, basemap

We pull in basemaps into our mapping tools, but we would like to remove all labels, not just the reference layer's labels of a basemap. I'm struggling with how to achieve this without having to build a basemap through reverse engineering. This basemap:
https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a2eae30d60e34cafaff0cc28f8edc324
is the closest I've found, but I can't see a way to add this item to my ArcGIS Portal/Enterprise so that I can add it to our tools. What am I missing?

Comment: Build it yourself.